# How to set global mutation in module vuex js store

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I need to be able to change the state of the global variable `alert` from any Vuex module.

**store/index.js**:

```
export const state = () => ({
    alert: null 
})
```

**store/child.js**:

```
export const mutations = {
    SET_ALERT: function (rootState, alert) {
        rootState.alert = alert
    }
}
export const actions = {
    setalert({commit}){
        commit('SET_ALERT', 'warning')
    }
}
```

I want to call `setalert` and set the global `store.state.alert` to `"warning"`. Currently, `store.state.child.alert` is getting set to `"warning"` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot access the state of a vuex module from within another module's mutation.

Right now your `SET_ALERT` mutation is referencing the `child` state because it is within the `child` module's scope. Changing the parameter name of the state object to `rootState` won't change what it is.

But, you can simply move the `SET_ALERT` mutation to be in the `index.js` file. The mutation can still be called from the `child` module's `setalert` action.

---

If you are using namespacing for the module (`namespace: true`), you will need to explicitly say to use the root module in the `commit` call, like so:

```
commit('SET_ALERT', 'warning', { root: true });
```

[Here's the documentation for Vuex Modules.](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html)

Comment: not work: i move mutation `SET_ALERT` into `index.js`, and now i get error `[vuex] unknown local mutation type: SET_ALERT, global type: articles/SET_ALERT`, any ideas?

Comment: Are you using namespacing?

Comment: `commit('SET_ALERT', 'warning', { root: true });` - thats great! Now IT WORK, thanks! I'm not sure I understand you, I only learn this `vuex` in `nuxt` + `express`.

Comment: can you give a link to the documentation where you found out about `{ root: true }`?

Comment: @ВасилийБуторин sure thing, added it to the answer